# Using 'had been' as opposed to 'was'

Tags: american-english, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

I cannot figure out which version of this sentence sounds better.

> After Cortés’s army had been surrounded by Montezuma’s soldiers, this alliance turned out to be critical to Cortés’ victory.

Or

> After Cortés’s army was surrounded by Montezuma’s soldiers, this alliance turned out to be critical to Cortés’ victory

I understand that 'had been surrounded' is pluperfect so it happens further in the past. This seems to create a nice contrast between 'surrounded' and 'turned out to be.' However, I'm not really sure which version of the sentence sounds better.

Answer (score -1):

The second sentence is grammatically correct because of two reasons:
1. The conjunction  'after' gives the idea of precedence of the first event.
2. The chronology of  two events is not broken.
So two verb forms /Past Simple/ in the  second sentence are correct.